# How can MVC 3 Architecture be used along with WF4 in .Net 4.0 Framework

Tags: asp.net, wpf, asp.net-mvc-3, workflow-foundation-4

I need help / advice on the below scenario.

We are planning to develop a web application which can handles millions of transaction per week with the below technologies.
1. WF4 for Work Flow definition / Business logic etc..
2. WPF for Application Design

Question 1:
We are also considering MVC3. Is it really necessary to use MVC3 with WF4 or we can go ahead with the traditional WebForms? We have absolutely no idea and we are confused. Ultimately we want to increase the developers productivity time by decrease the coding time.

Question 2:
Is it possible to use MVC3 with WF4? If so, please provide me some resources. There is very limited resources for this combo.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-WF4-in-the-Real-World-Microsoft-Support-ASPNET-MVC-Wizard-Framework) video. It may introduce you to some key aspects of workflow usage in conjunction with ASP.NET MVC and that may lead you to take some decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance in MVC is going to be better 'out of the box' so to say because of the lack of viewstate and the ability for lightweight responses using JSON.
If you are looking at a high performance site and aren't sure what to use - I would recommend MVC. There will be a slight learning curve but in the end I think you will be thankful you did. Unit testing alone is so much easier.

re workflow:
Since code can trigger off a workflow, you absolutely can use it. Just call your workflow, there's nothing special there. 
The first google result for running from asp.net
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163623.aspx

You can expose your workflow via a service, call directly, etc.